# Magento limit the number of products shown with in the new products block

Tags: xml, magento, limit, product

How to limit the number of products shown with in the new products block?
via cms/pages/design/Layout update XML

```
<block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" >
   <action method="setColumnCount"><count>5</count></action> 
   <action method="setLimit"><limit>5</limit></action>
</block>
```

setLimit does not work, nor does

```
<action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>5</limit></action>
```

or:

```
<action method="setData"><key>limit</key><value>3</value></action>
```

or:

```
<action method="setProductLimit"><count>5</count></action>
```

or:

```
<action method="setProductsLimit"><count>5</count></action>
```

or:

```
<action method="setProductsCount"><count>5</count></action>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
 <action method="setProductsCount"><count>5</count></action>
```

See /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/New.php

```
/**
 * Set how much product should be displayed at once.
 *
 * @param $count
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New
 */
public function setProductsCount($count)
{
    $this->_productsCount = $count;
    return $this;
}
```

Read more @ http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/248/display_products_on_home_page

Comment: You are right! I tested this on a fresh new install of magento and it worked. I found out that there was an overwriting module wich used the reserved namesapace. Thats why it wouldn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try it randomly. You're trying to call an action on a `block/product_new`. So go into the class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` and see what function could do the job (double Ctrl+O in eclipse)

Here i see a `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract::addColumnCountLayoutDepend($pageLayout, $columnCount)` function.

Maybe it can help you. Example:

```
$this->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('one_column', 5)
```