# In magento how do you limit the amount of items in the new product xml?

Tags: magento, rss, limit

Hi I've set up the new product xml and can access it via 
http:/xxxxxxxx.com/index.php/rss/catalog/new/store_id/1/

But I'm having trouble because it is trying to get all the products and is causing (at times some memory problems)

Any help would be great!
Thanks
Richard

Answer (score 2):

I believe this has been previously discussed: [Magento limit the number of products shown with in the new products block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050587/magento-limit-the-number-of-products-shown-with-in-the-new-products-block)

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Dan

Comment: Hi thanks Dan I did see that but they are discussing - I think the new product block in magento - it's different to the new products xml feed. Although the search terms bring up the same stuff